# Javascript/AJAX, PHP, and MySQL checkout

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

brand new to AJAX so I'm having a tough time finding a resource for my specific situation.

I am attempting a simple checkout system utilizing a MYSQL database with a table layout like so:

[image: mysql table layout]

Right now my site layout looks like:

1. Dropdown menu with "Check In" or "Check Out" options
2. Dropdown menu with each item name in the table (using PHP to access)
3. Submit button

The next thing to do is create a function for the submit button that increments or decrements the "Available" column for the item selected. I understand that this is where ajax comes in since I need to send the selected ID for PHP to use.

My only experience with ajax is [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) which is similar to what I want to do, but not quite the same. I know the function I want to use will look something like this:

```
function updateStuff() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
       // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else {
       // code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","update.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

But it's not the same, because I need to use the id's of the currently selected option in each of the two dropdowns to determine what happens with the table.

So do I need to back up and get some understanding of AJAX? Or is there a simple enough way to edit this for my purposes where I don't need to have a complete understanding to make this work.

Comment: You would need two buttons, firing up two different functions, which in turn would fire up two different calls to DB. `UPDATE table SET column_x = column_x +1 WHERE column_y='Camera1'` basically.

Comment: Or he could treat the check-in/check-out input as the directive for the action on the server side instead of using 2 different ajax endpoints... Unless I am misunderstanfing.

Comment: @prodigitalson I made a bit of an edit to my comment above. However, OP states: *"The next thing to do is create a function for the submit button that increments or decrements the "Available" column for the item selected."* - Which is what I gathered from it.

Comment: No i get tha I was saying let the selctor for check-in check-out determin whether you update does `column_x-1` or `column_x+1`... Also i just realized I have been using JQ so long i don't recall how to process and serialize a form for AJAX with vanilla js... TIS A SAD DAY :-(

Comment: prodigitalson you are correct, if "Check In" is selected, then the amount available increases by one, and if "Check Out" is selected, then the amount available decreases by one, so all this AJAX stuff aside I think I just need one Submit button.

Comment: @prodigitalson I get ya. Anything can be done, just need to put our minds to it ;-)

Comment: You would need a listener then.

Comment: Would I be better off spending my time learning JQuery then to accomplish this?

Comment: You're still going to need Ajax to process the PHP. For on-the-spot processing anyway.

Comment: Right - but wouldn't JQuery simplify this?

Comment: You don't really need jQuery. You could if you want, but all you really need is some form of JS that will interact with your DB and capable to interact with PHP at the same time. Those fall hand in hand.

Answer (score 1):

There would be a method not very safe. try to utilize jquery use so:

```
$ ('# yourid'). load ('page_id.php?str=' + str)
```

and in php page page_id.php

```
<?php
$str=$_GET['str'];
//open connection db and select your string from your db ex. SELECT FROM USER WHERE USER='$str'

echo $results
?>
```

is not beautiful, but it might help you, because you send a variable to the php page. that queries the database later.
if you need to change the page of course not ...